# MAX889 Output voltage dropping

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage

I am using [MAX889TESA+](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX889.pdf) for generating -3.3V from 3.3V input. The schematic is as below.

[image]

I am feeding the output from this regulator to the 8 sets of [AD8066](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/609/AD8065_8066-1502028.pdf). When the 1 set of AD8066 is connected the output voltage from regulator is -3.1V but when I connect more than 1 set of AD8066 circuits the voltage is completely dropping.

1set of AD8066

[image]

My questions are:-

1.Is regulator output current sufficient to drive 8 sets AD8066?

2.I am supplying 3.3V to regulator and generating -3.3V is this correct?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Please include a schematic of _your_ design (not the reference schematic from the datasheet) that shows how the op amps are connected.

Comment: That regulator can supply 200mA, so unlikely that a single opamp is overloading it. What does the layout of your circuit look like? How much current are you pulling when it drops to -3.1?

Comment: @TypeIA I have updated snapshots

Comment: @user1850479 I have not measured current

Comment: Have you measured voltage on the positive rail when the charge pump drops out?

Comment: @TypeIA Yes its 3.3V

Comment: What are the expected voltages on the buffer amplifier inputs and outputs?